# Отправка потока getUserMedia на сервер Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, видео

Задача: отправить видеопоток с вэбки клиента на сервер. Код клиента:

```
var socket = io(":9966");

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });

    var video = document.querySelector('video');

        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
            console.log(stream);
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            var arrayOfStreams = [stream];
            var medias = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
            medias.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
                socket.emit("streaming", blob);
            };
            medias.start();
            socket.emit("streaming", stream);
            socket.emit('test', 'mess from 1');

        });
```

Сервер

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
log.info('new con!', socket.id);

socket.send("you connected to server");

socket.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.send(data);
});

socket.on('streaming', function (stream) {
    log.info("i`m in stream", socket.id);
    log.info(stream);
    //socket.broadcast.send(stream);
    socket.broadcast.emit('streaming', stream);
});
});
```

При отправке простых текстовых сообщений всё работает как надо,а вот при отправке видео получаю пустое значение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К Гуглу обращался, но не получилось реализовать(.   Буду рад любой помощи.  И ещё вопрос на засыпку: как потом полученный от сервера поток преобразовать обратно в видео?

Comment: я бы рекомендовал остановиться и почитать документацию https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем именно про потоки node js читать? Тут вроде речь идёт о совсем другом потоке, разве нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял из вашего кода, вы из одного браузера получаете поток и хотите через сокеты передать всем юзерам в канале. Я бы посоветовал для этого использовать webrtc. Просто подключитесь ко всем по webrtc и передавайте напрямую.

Если же вам вот обязательно нужен сервер, о нужно поступить хитрее. [MediaStreamRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) при наличие данных возвращает [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob). Данные из него прочитать можно только через [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Попробуйте прочитать этот блок как base64 строку и вот её и отправить. На сервере вы можете раскодировать и сохранить куда-нибудь или отправить другим участникам.

Для того, чтоб обратно закодировать стрим, попробуйте превратить эту base64 строку обратно в блоб и через `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` установите как адрес видео. Идея в этом.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ) На самом деле вопрос уже решил в том же ключе что и Вы описали. (Не успел ответить сам на свой вопрос.) В любом случае спасибо, хоть убедился, что сейчас всё сделал нормально.